# sql records get the most recent records -SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
ID,FID,DATE_ADDED
75,67,2020-07-29 11:19:37.5230000   
76,67 ,2020-07-29 11:31:51.1870000      
77,23,2020- 07-29 11:15:44.2230000
```

I have this record set however I would like to return a record set of the most recent entries for the FID

```
76,67 ,2020-07-29 11:31:51.1870000      
77,23,2020- 07-29 11:15:44.2230000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `row_number()`

```
select * from
(
select *,row_number() over(partition by fid order by date_added desc) as rn
from tablename
)A where rn=1
```

Answer (score 1):

A correlated subquery is a simple and efficient method:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.date_added = (select max(t2.date_added) from t t2 where t2.fid = t.fid);
```